# jsonlite::fromJSON failed to connect to Port 443 in quantmod getFX()

Tags: r, firewall

I needed a function which automatically gets the Exchange Rate from a website (oanda.com), therefore I used the quantmod package and made a function based on that.

```
library(quantmod)

ForeignCurrency<-"MYR" # has to be a character

getExchangeRate<-function(ForeignCurrency){ 
  Conv<-paste("EUR/",(ForeignCurrency),sep="")
  getFX(Conv,from=Sys.Date()-179,to=Sys.Date())
  
  Conv2<-paste0("EUR",ForeignCurrency,sep="")
  
  Table<-as.data.frame(get(Conv2))
  ExchangeRate<-1/mean(Table[,1])
  ExchangeRate
}
ExchangeRate<-getExchangeRate(ForeignCurrency)

ExchangeRate
```

On my personal PC, it works perfectly and do what I want. If i run this on the working PC, I get following Error:

> ```
> Warning: Unable to import “EUR/MYR”.
> Failed to connect to www.oanda.com port 443: Timed out
> ```

I googled already a lot, it seems to be a Firewall Problem, but none of the suggestions I found there doesnt work. After checking the getFX() function, the Problem seems to be in the jsonlite::fromJSON function which getFX() is using.

Did someone of you faced a similar Problem? I am quite familar with R, but with Firewalls/Ports I have no expertise. Do I have to change something in the R settings or is it a Problem independent of R and something in the Proxy settings needs to be changed?

Can you please help :-) ?

Comment: `jsonlite::fromJSON` is just parsing the JSON data that was downloaded. But according to the error message the network connection failed. This is almost certainly unrelated to jsonlite.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. Than I was wrong assuming the Errors appears at the jsonlite::fromJSON step (based on debugging and looking at the source code I was assuming that). I will try to find out where the error is, may that helps to find a solution for this Problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows how you can do a workaround for the getfx() in an enterprise context where you often have to go through a proxy to the internet.

```
library(httr)

# url that you can find inside https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/blob/master/R/getSymbols.R
url <- "https://www.oanda.com/fx-for-business//historical-rates/api/data/update/?&source=OANDA&adjustment=0&base_currency=EUR&start_date=2022-02-17&end_date=2022-02-17&period=daily&price=mid&view=table&quote_currency_0=VND"
# original call inside the quantmod library: # Fetch data (jsonlite::fromJSON will handle connection) tbl <- jsonlite::fromJSON(oanda.URL, simplifyVector = FALSE)

# add the use_proxy with your proxy address and proxy port to get through the proxy
response <- httr::GET(url, use_proxy("XX.XX.XX.XX",XXXX))

status <- status_code(response)
if(status == 200){
  content <- httr::content(response)

  # use jsonlite to get the single attributes like quote currency, exchange rate = average and base currency
  exportJson <- jsonlite::toJSON(content, auto_unbox = T)
  getJsonObject <- jsonlite::fromJSON(exportJson, flatten = FALSE)
  print(getJsonObject$widget$quoteCurrency)
  print(getJsonObject$widget$average)
  print(getJsonObject$widget$baseCurrency)
}
```